# How can I convert an Object type to a int type in Java?

Tags: java, oop, casting

I'm looking for a way to convert a `Object` type (as in the wildcard type which can store many different types) to an `int` type. In all of my searching I have not found an answer to this question on the site.

I have a `Object[]` array which stores only integers and I need to perform some math using one of the integers. For example `int result = array[3] + 2;`. This arithmetic won't work unless I can cast/convert that `Object` to an `int`.

Comment: If your `Object[]` array only stores integers, why not use `Integer[]` or `int[]` instead? This would make your life easier.

Comment: What's wrong with casting `Object` to `Int`?

Comment: Try to cast it to `Integer` and unbox it to `int` afterwards.

Comment: If you manage to get an instance of `Integer` (for example by casting `Integer x = (Integer) someObject;`), the unboxing (change from Integer to int, Long to long, etc.) is done automatically, e.g. `Integer x = 3; int y = x;`

Comment: Downvoted as redundant. The problem is with the `Object[]` array itself, not what you want to do with its elements afterwards. Classic XY problem.

Comment: [`Object.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) will convert any `Object` to an `int`. Not sure that **really** helps you though.

Comment: @LKTN.25 solved it, if you submit it as an answer I can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The others that say `Integer[]` and `int[]` are the solutions to the question is very **true** when only numbers will be added in the array. But, In some cases, there are requirements that we should follow. So `Object` that contains number can be casted to `Integer` and unbox it to `int` is more likely what the OP needs.

Comment: If the `Object` contains a "number" it is not necessarily cast-able to `Integer`... Use `((Number)obj).intValue()` instead...

Comment: The OP has specifically stated that it 'stores only integers`'

Comment: yes I agree Sir @EJP , the OP says that he will store only numbers but he uses Object[] instead of `Integer[]` or `int[]`. `List<Integer>` will do it too, but as I can see, The OP wants that way, and there is some reason why that we don't know. For the mean time, I think that we should answer what he wants, but advice him and others that this kind of operation is not right.

Comment: I am commenting on your statement that the other answers are 'very true when only numbers will be added in the array'. The OP has already clearly stated that this is 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

if yourself define object array,I think u can use int array,if other method return this data type,u can convert to int,but u need check object array element whether is not

Answer (score -1):

> I have a `Object[]` array which stores only integers

Solution: don't. Use `Integer[]`, or better still `int[]`, as @dave has already told you.

The suggestion to cast the objects twice is inefficient and error-prone.

Don't cause downstream problems for yourself by weak typing.

As a side benefit, if your assertion that it stores only integers turns out to be untrue, you will now find out at compile time, instead of at runtime.

Comment: Requires it why? Your 'workflow' requires you to build in deliberate inefficencies at both ends of the process?

Comment: Calling people names doesn't answer the questions they ask you, and it is very often the case that the correct answer lies in changing something upstream. Requires it why? I also find nothing stated about these alleged workflow requirements in your question.

Comment: So it wasn’t clear that I asked for a way to turn an Object into an int? Sounds like a requirement that’s part of my workflow

Comment: No it doesn't. It sounds like an XY problem, and the more you refuse to disclose your actual requirement, the more it does so. The name-calling on the other hand definitely *isn't* part of *any* requirement.